# importing C++/Qt module in QML

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml, qt-creator, qt5

I have made a module to execute a shell script from within QML. The problem that I'm having is that I don't know how to import the module into my QML script. This is for a UT application BTW.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtqml/tutorials-extending-chapter6-plugins.html) from the Qt tutorials gives a good description of how to write a QML plugin in C++.  I won't repeat all the details, but the basic idea is that you need to make a new class, inheriting from `QQmlExtensionPlugin`, to represent the plugin.  It must have a `registerTypes` method, in which `qmlRegisterType` is called on each class to be exposed to QML.  Additionally, a qmldir file must be added to the directory containing the `.so` files.  (Or it can be put in another directory, but include the location of the `.so` files in the plugin line.)

I just got done learning this myself, and I've [written up what I've learned](http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/14/reading-files-with-a-c%2B%2B-plugin-in-qml.html), if that's any help.